# Using ISNULL on an int? in the WHERE clause of Linq queries

Tags: c#, linq

I have been trying to find a resolution to this and I've seen many examples of how to use the `ISNULL` functionality in a `SELECT` statement, or how to check for nulls in a `WHERE` clause to return a boolean value.

However I can't find any examples through my searches of how to return an integer depending on whether or not the value is null.

I'm trying to replicate a simple piece of functionality from SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Projects 
WHERE ISNULL(projects.ParentID , 0) = @Value
```

I've tried a few different methods based on suggestions I've seen relating to `SELECT` clauses or `ISNULL` boolean operations in the `WHERE` clause throughout my searches:

```
var output = (from p in ctx.Projects...
```

1.

```
...
where ( (p.ParentID == null) ? p.ParentID == 0 : p.ParentID == p.ParentID) == @var
```

2.

```
...
where p.ParentID ?? 0 == @var
```

3.

```
...
where p.ParentID ? 0 == @var
```

4.

```
...
where ((p.ParentID == null) ? true : 0 ) == @var
```

5.

```
...
where 
((p.ParentID == null) ? 0 ) == @var
```

`...select p` )

Any help would be appreciated, I'm at a loss as to why this is so complex in Linq compared to SQL.

Comment: And what were the results in those cases (note that "didn't work" is not a problem description)?

Comment: There's also .HasValue to check if a nullable var is null.

Comment: How about this then: `ctx.Projects.Where(x => !x.ParentID.HasValue && value == 0)`

Comment: The direct equivalent is `??` operator. Why do you think `(p.ParentID ?? 0)` is more complex than `ISNULL(p.ParentID, 0)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
var q = ctx.Projects.Where(p => p.ParentId == parentId);
```

That works if `parentId` is an `int` or `int?`.

If you treat the null as 0 this should work:

```
 var q = ctx.Projects.Where(p => (p.ParentId ?? 0) == parentId);
```

Comment: Because he needs to check if parentId is null and value is zero then it’s true. Check his sql query

Comment: This was second suggestion looks to be the resolution. Similar to my trial 2 but I was missing the parenthesis. Thank you kindly.

Comment: This will generated sql like '(CASE WHEN p.ParentID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE p.ParentID) = @Var' which is a bit complicated.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
where (p.ParentId == value) || (value == 0 && p.ParentId == null)
```

Because value == 0 is already known as the time the query is generated so you will earn some performance.

Comment: this does look like it will solve my issue, however I have elected to go for Tim's suggestion below as to me it reads cleaner. Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: Check the generated sql in other answer. You will see the complex SWITCH CASE in SQL.